# table cell crashes when i swipe to delete. Getting bad access error

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, tableview

i keep getting this error on my table view when i swipe to delete, the general edit button puts it into edit mode and i can delete it fine with that, but if i swipe a cell it crashes and returns a bad access error.  I'm assuming theres some data conversation error somewhere, but i don't understand.  i can delete it fine using edit and tapping the cell, but swiping crashes it.  I have this view controller which creates a table view.  Heres the code:

in my view controller i have this code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self controllerSetup];

}

-(void)controllerSetup
{


        firstController = [[TeacherSplitTableController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
        [firstTable setDataSource:firstController];
        [firstTable setDelegate:firstController];
        firstController.view = firstController.tableView;
        [firstController setDelegate:self];
        [self tableSetUp];

}

-(IBAction)edit:(id)sender
{
    if (!editting) {
            editting = YES;
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(Add:)];
        //Displays add button over the back button
            [self.firstTable setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    } else {
            editting = NO;
            self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = NO;
            [self.firstTable setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }

}
```

the teachersplittablecontroller code is here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        [self openDB];
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM Children WHERE Name = '%@' ",[listofnames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; //Queries table for the childs name and returns more data.
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(Childdb, [sql UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil)==SQLITE_OK){
                    while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
                    }
        }


        [listofnames removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [listoftickets removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //[theDataObject.names removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //[theDataObject.totaltickets removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self setEditing:editing animated:YES];


}
```

tried to keep the code slim and in relation to the question.  If you require any more code just ask.  But i can't see the problem :(  Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self setEditing:editing animated:YES];
}
```

Looks to me like a nice endless loop.

Is there some computing time before the app crashes? 
If not - did you enable zombies?

Comment: Actually it is, takes around 2 seconds for xcode to process the crash.  Enable zombies? - lol

Comment: You mean the simulator, not xcode? Well, if it takes some time then I would assume that the loop is causing it. Do you acutally see the loop in there? Regarding zombies ... do you know what I am referring to? It is a nice option where released objects are not re-used in debug mode and access to it creates a regluar exception so that tracing the root cause is much easier. Strange name though but quite useful.

Comment: no, on my iPad, thats what i'm using to test it.  the xcode takes about 2 seconds to respond to the crash, usually instant.  But, i'm using this code on other view controllers as well.  AND why does it crash when i swipe the cell, and does swipping the cell even call this method?

Comment: Can you repeat that on the simulator too or does it happen on the device only?

Comment: It happens on the simulator too.  No change, it takes a little longer to respond to the crash though

Comment: Well, did you get rid of the loop in the meantime? BTW why do you call [self setEditing:] within setEditing at all?